Comparing clusterings from different datasets
I have 2 different data sets with essentially the same variables, though one is data from one year and the other is data from another year. I've run KModes on both data sets and now have some clusterings/clusterization. Now, I want to see how similar the clustering from the first data set is to the second data set.
I've tried using ARI (Adjusted Rand Index), and inserting dummy labels into the smaller data set, or randomly sampling from the larger data set, but I keep getting ARI scores that are ridiculously low, even though certain clusterings look to be really really similar. I'm wondering if there is any other methodology for doing the comparison that I'm trying to do, or if my use of ARI was improper somehow.
If ARI has a legitimate use case for my purposes, how would I go about comparing 2 different sized clusterizations using ARI? And if not, what options do I have for doing the comparison?

Please tell us more about your data. Size / number of rows/instances, number of variables/features, types of variables/features, how the data were collected etc. Also, what is your ultimate goal of the analysis ? Suppose you get some measure of how similar the clusters are - then what ?

Clusterizations that contain between 4-8 variables with 10-15 clusters per clusterization. All variables have categorical values. The only difference between the 2 data sets is that one data set contains data from one year and the other from another year. The first year has a size of around 11000 and the second year has a size of around 10000 data points. If we can find similarities between clusterization in year one and year two, we can find trends (i.e. variables that commonly form together between years)

Thanks for that. It would be a good idea if you can edit this extra info into your post - that way other people will be able to see what the problem/question is without having to delve into comments.. So, as far as I know, there aren't many alternatives fo ARI for this  purpose. However, given that your goal seems to be that you want to understand the trend over the period. If that is the case ? (please confirm) then a completely different approach (ie not using clustering) might be appropriate. - is there any reason for using clustering here - a regression model might be work looking at ?

Sorry for the delay in reply. For various reasons (some of them more "bureaucratic"), the methodology of KModes is one that I have to use. If ARI is the approach, how should I implement it? ARI requires that the two input clusterizations are the same size, and I'm not exactly sure how to deal with that discrepancy in my case, given that the clusterizations are from different data sets, and therefore have different lengths.

I think the more heuristic approach below could be useful.
For both datasets, find the average of each cluster. Then, using the Year 1 clustering as a reference, match each cluster against the closest Year 2 cluster (e.g. shortest Euclidean distance between the two cluster means).
For each resulting pair, you can start by assuming that they are 'matching clusters' between the two datasets, and then proceed to assess how similar they are and how they differ.
You might also find that they are not meaningfully similar. If the closest matches are not meaningfully similar, then the two clusterings might have found very different structures, making direct comparison less meaningful.
